# How can I change a color of row by index

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a table with cell editing using primeng which the data its completed by a API, so the table never has the same quantity of rows and the same order. I want to change the row color to red if the word size is wrong or green if the size is correct.

I think I need to take the index of the edited row and then change the color.

```
<p-table [value]="valProd" responsiveLayout="scroll" (onEditInit)="onEditInit($event)" (onEditCancel)="onCancelInit($event)"> 
  <ng-template pTemplate="header"> 
    <tr> 
     <th>Name</th> 
     <th>Value</th> 
     <th>Size</th> 
    </tr> 
  </ng-template> 
   <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-valProd let-rowData> 
      <tr> 
      <td>
        <p-cellEditor>
         <ng-template pTemplate="output">
           {{ rowData.Name}}
         </ng-template>
       </p-cellEditor>
     </td>
         <td [pEditableColumn]="rowData.Value" pEditableColumnField="rowData.Value"> 
          <p-cellEditor [ngStyle]="{'background': colorTry}"> 
           <ng-template pTemplate="input"> 
            <input pInputText 
              type="text" 
              [(ngModel)]="rowData.Value" 
              name="value"
              (change)="checkWriteValue(rowData.Value, rowData.Size, rowData.HasFixedLength, rowData.Name)"
                                (keydown.enter)="checkWriteValue(rowData.Value, rowData.Size, rowData.HasFixedLength, rowData.name)"
> 
          </ng-template> 
          <ng-template pTemplate="output" id="pruebainput"> 
            {{rowData.Value}}
          </ng-template> 
        </p-cellEditor> 
      </td> 

      <td>
        <p-cellEditor>
         <ng-template pTemplate="output">
           {{ rowData.Size}}
         </ng-template>
       </p-cellEditor>
     </td>
   </tr> 
 </ng-template> 
</p-table>
```

I tried using the ngstyle but all the rows are painted. I need to work with them independently.

The purpose is when the cells ends the edit pressing enter or losing the focus, check the size of the word, then if the size is correct change de row background to green or red. It is possible have more than one in the same color.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try to do it on pure CSS. Because of PrimeNG has embedded validation (see the screenshot), just catch it.

Your CSS should be similar to as below (sorry, hasn't checked):

```
tr {
  background: green;
}

tr:has(.ng-dirty.ng-invalid) {
  background: red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried but all the rows take the style, I can't get them to be for the rows that have been modified.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this issue.

The first solution involves rendering rows in color if their default values meet the condition.
On the other hand, the second solution does not render rows with color unless they have 'ng-dirty', but only if they have 'ng-dirty'.

**First Solution**

To address this, you can use ngClass to set the row background color.

In your HTML, you can use ngClass as follows:

```
<tr
    [ngClass]="{'not-valid-length': rowData.Value.length > 10, 'valid-length' : rowData.Value.length < 10}"
  >
    ...
  </tr>
```

For your CSS class, use 'not-valid-length', and for the condition to append the class to the table row, use 'rowData.Value.length'.

In your CSS/SCSS file, add the following lines:

```
    :host ::ng-deep .not-valid-length {
     background-color: rgba(185, 24, 24, 0.15) !important;
    }

    :host ::ng-deep .valid-length {
     background-color: rgba(102, 185, 24, 0.15) !important;
    }
```

**Second Solution**

To set the color of a table row after the input cell has been changed, edit the body template as follows: add 'let-i="rowIndex"' to the template and manipulate the row within the template.

```
let-i="rowIndex"
```

- 

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-valProd let-rowData let-i="rowIndex">... 
</ng-template>
```

After this, add 'rowIndex' to the table row:

```
<tr [id]="'tableRow' + i">...</tr>
```

The 'i' parameter is added with the rowIndex into this template.

This ensures that all rows will have unique IDs, allowing identification of the edited input cell's row.The row index is necessary in the checkWriteValue method to set the row color, so in the HTML, checkWriteValue method is updated accordingly.

```
<p-cellEditor [ngStyle]="{'background': colorTry}">
        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
          <input
            id="input"
            pInputText
            type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="rowData.Value"
            name="value"
            (change)="checkWriteValue($event, i)"
            (keydown.enter)="checkWriteValue($event, i)"
          />
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="output" id="pruebainput">
          {{rowData.Value}}
        </ng-template>
 </p-cellEditor>
```

After completing these steps, the component.ts file can be edited.

```
checkWriteValue(event: any, index: number) {
let input: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('input');
let tableRow: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('tableRow' + index);
if (input.classList.value.includes('ng-dirty')) {
  if (event.target.value.length > 10) {
    tableRow.classList?.remove('valid-length');
    tableRow.classList.add('not-valid-length');
  } else {
    tableRow.classList?.remove('not-valid-length');
    tableRow.classList.add('valid-length');
  }
}
```

}

The checkWriteValue method takes 'event' and 'index' as inputs and adds CSS classes to the table row. It includes two 'if' statements:The first checks for 'ng-dirty' in the input's class list,and the second checks the length of the input's new value to determine which CSS class is appropriate.This results in the addition of 'not-valid-length' or 'valid-length' classes to the row's class list. *(edit note: Because the previous class is not deleted, the code starts to behave buggy at some point. That's why the classList.remove('valid-length') and other methods were added. The buggy situation can be observed by commenting out those lines.)*

Please note that I am uncertain about the type of your value. It is assumed to be a string.

Be cautious when using :host and ::ng-deep.

I have tested my solution and it works well. You can try it out [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kdkxdw-q5zqmp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftable-style-demo.html).

If you have any further questions, I am happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you are using react, one workaround would be to have an array with minimum of 50 colors for example.
Then you loop through the data and create rows dynamically and for each row you add inline style with background color based on that index.

```
const colors = ['#a2a2a2','#e2e2e2','#515151',...];

data.map((item,i)=>(
<row style={{backgroundColor:colors[i]}}></row>
));
```

---

But, if you have are using javascript you can use css :nth-child. and add background color for each row.

Comment: I'm using Angular with PrimeNg, the color must be changed when the word size is incorrect and also when is correct

Comment: Then you should use js to add a class based on the Status of the row. Like .notCorrect and .isCorrect .